# jQuery - cut html string to place items in arrays

Tags: jquery

I have a string that looks like this:

```
my_str = "<h1>title</h1><p>parag1</p><p>parag2</p> (more paragraphs)";
```

I'd like to create two arrays : `arr_tags (contains 'h1', 'p', 'p')` and `arr_contents (contains 'title', 'parag1', 'parag2')`.

I first thought "splice" and "split" methods, but I do not see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more version with [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/), [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) and [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

```
var my_str = "<h1>title</h1><p>parag1</p><p>parag2</p>";
var arr_tags = [];
var arr_contents = [];

$(my_str).each(function()
{
    arr_tags.push($(this).prop("tagName"));
    arr_contents.push($(this).text());
});

console.log(arr_tags);
console.log(arr_contents);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3f2ff71a/2/).

Comment: Beat me to it :P I did this! Only I used `arr_tags.push(this.nodeName)`

Comment: @Mardoxx I usually end up with such thoughts. But not this time :)

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy if you indeed use jQuery, it has a [map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) function for this:

```
$(function () {
    var my_str = "<h1>title</h1><p>parag1</p><p>parag2</p>";

    var $tags = $(my_str).map(function() {
        return this.tagName;
    }).get();

    var $texts = $(my_str).map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();

    console.log($tags);
    console.log($texts);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agqdum1p/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`jQuery.parseHTML`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/):

```
var html = $.parseHTML("<h1>title</h1><p>parag1</p><p>parag2</p>");
$.each(html, function(i, el ) {
  console.log(el);
  console.log(el.nodeName)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The non-jQuery answer.

```
var tags = document.createElement('div');
tags.innerHTML = my_str;

var children = [].slice.call(tags.children);
var elements = children.map(function(child) {
  return child.tagName;
});
var contents = children.map(function(child) {
  return child.textContent;
});
```